# C++ segmentation fault in linked list class member function

Tags: c++, debugging, compiler-errors, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I have created a nested class (LinkedList and Node) to implement a linked list class in C++, but I am having segmentation fault errors with a few of my class member functions. I have spent multiple hours trying to figure out what the errors are because I have been using Microsoft Virtual Studio to compile my code and it doesn't catch any segmentation fault errors for any of my test cases, but different compilers do catch the errors.

For instance, my updated`GetNode()` function (which is supposed to return a pointer to the node at a given index and then throw an exception of type out_of_range if the index is out of range) is as follows:

```
    const Node* GetNode(unsigned index) const {
    Node* cour = head;
    
    // we can't return nullptr, we must throw
    while(test) {
       // if index is zero, return courser pointer
       if(!index) return cour;
       test = test->next; 
       --index;
    } 
    throw out_of_range("Error: out of range");
}
```

I type casted index to integer because count is an integer and I wasn't sure if the different data types would cause an issue. Head is the first node of the linked list. Next is the pointer to the next node. The first index of the linked list should be 0 and then the last one should be count - 1. I would really appreciate any help here. I can post the code of other functions that are giving me the segmentation fault error if requested.

Comment: Maybe count is wrong. The code blindly  does `test = test->next;`  assuming there are enough items in the list but if count is wrong it can walk off the end of the list.

Comment: @Slash I think the problem is in some other function. By the way is it possible that count is greater than 0 and head is equal to nullptr at the same time?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow It's possible, but I am 95% sure that count cannot be greater than 0 if head is nullptr in my code.

Comment: @drescherjm That would make sense but I don't think the count value is wrong in my code. I'll take a look though.

Comment: I think the problem with your testing is not the compiler / IDE. I would expect Visual Studio Community in debug mode to break into the debugger on an access violation caused by an invalid pointer. I think the problem with your testing procedure is you are not using the same test case as this online compiler that appears in your Error picture.

Comment: `(int)index` on an `unsigned` in general is a bad idea, because index might be too big so it would become negative.

Comment: Please don't remove your question after it has been answered/resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If you know for certain that `count` is the actual length of the list then the only possible way for your code to cause a seg fault is if `index` exceeds the largest possible 32-bit integer (and `count`), and casting that value into an `int` causes it to wrap around to a value between `0` and `count`, making the initial `if` statement pass. Then the for loop iterates using that large number, causing `test` to reach the end of the list and dereferencing that null pointer would cause a segmentation fault.

Here is code that doesn't have that flaw:

```
const Node* GetNode(unsigned int index) const {
  while (index--) {
    if (!test)
      break;
    test = test->next;
  }
  return !test ? throw out_of_range("Error: out of range") : test;
}
```

The problem might still be elsewhere, but in your code the only two issues are the one I just explained, and if `count` isn't the actual length of the list.

Comment: Thank you for the help but unfortunately, my code has the segmentation fault error elsewhere in the code.  I'll try installing a different compiler to catch the segmentation fault error later to debug.

Comment: @Slash segfaults usually happen too late in relation to actual error in judgement. Compilers guarantee consistent behaviour when you doing legal stuff, but not when you do illegal. In latter case program either _may_ work , work incorrectly or do nothing at all What you would need is a debugger

Answer (score 0):

Your version of function exhibits Undefined Behaviour in case if index is incorrectly big (larger than MAX_INT) or if head is `nullptr`. Generally speaking do not allow any case where a function that return value may not return. Some compilers have a quirk to generate an incorrect code in that case, *intentionally* to avoid masquerade of missed edge cases. It should look at least like:

```
const Node* GetNode(unsigned int index) const {
    if ((int)index < count && (int)index >= 0 && head != nullptr) {
        Node* test = head;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < index; ++i) {
            test = test->next;
        }
        return test;
    }
  
    throw out_of_range("Error: out of range");
}
```

`(int)index` on a `unsigned` and in general such cast style are not recommended. The function also assumes that there is  enough  elements in list

You have to also assume that `head` maybe non-null but index is zero and vice versa.

If index is zero-based then while `index=N-1`, N-th element can be `nullptr`, we're returning one before it. I.e. if `index=0`, then we are returning `head` if it's not `nullptr`. At `index=1` we are returning `head->next` if it's not `nullptr`, and so on.

Possible solution (it assumes index is zero based):

```
const Node* GetNode(unsigned index) const {
    Node* cour = head;
    
    // we can't return nullptr, we must throw
    while(test) {
       // if index is zero, return courser pointer
       if(!index) return cour;
       test = test->next; 
       --index;
    } 
    throw out_of_range("Error: out of range");
}
```

So far, you appear to "know" some invariant `count` which may allow a short circuit check. But what type it is? Your cast suggest it being an `int`.

In real life an `unsigned int` parameter for index may be a design flaw unless you can ensure its correct usage at all times. Especially if actually stored parameter is an `int`. A negative value would get converted to very large positive, which may result in lock-up of program if your algorithm is built like one provided in question.

If you're casting unsigned to signed, you're already in gray area. If you're comparing unsigned to signed, you're allowing a similar error because its wrongdoing is the the *implicit* cast. You just made compiler to trust that you actually want such check.

If parameter is signed, passing a too large unsigned value as an argument of function results in a negative value of parameter:

```
const Node* GetNode(int index) const {
    Node* cour = head;

    // we can't return nullptr, we must throw
    if(index > 0 && index < count)
       while(test) {
         // if index is zero, return courser pointer
         if(!index) return cour;
         test = test->next; 
         --index;
       } 
    throw out_of_range("Error: out of range");
}
```

That seems a little paranoid, we assume here that `count` may be bad. You may add explicit check for head being `nullptr` and do a while-loop with index decrement, if you can trust the invariance of `count`.

In real life invariants can't be trusted 100% of time and should be checked in debug builds, the issue there isn't only a logic error but accidental data race, stale pointer dereference or an out-of-bound write somewhere in program. In that case  diagnostics may be different, e.g. signaling a logic error instead of out-of-bound.